# Why does mysql_real_escape_string insert quotes where there shouldn't be?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page that I use to import orders from a csv file into a mysql database. One varchar in the table is used for the txnid. I discovered that occasionally I'll come across a txnid that results in an "Illegal double value found during parsing" error. For example:

```
6L831105EP011602
```

is a fine value that doesn't cause any trouble.

```
71V72876YH791094
```

Again, no problems.

```
546635980E5898057
```

But this one causes the error, presumably because it is being parsed as a double.

I have tried using mysql_real_escape_string to sanitize the data, but this results in all values being prefixed with `''` unless they would've been parsed as a double.

What is the correct way I should be sanitizing this data? How can I determine if a value is going to cause a parse error before I try to insert it into MySQL?

Comment: Do you know who is giving that error? I think it’s MySQL.

Comment: So, I think you need to show us how you map excel to mysql. Without that we can't tell much.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*`.

Comment: We'll need to see some code. Expect some chiding if you're writing new code [using the mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` does **NOT** add quotes to a string. It **ESCAPES** sql metacharacters.

e.g.

```
$str1 = "Miles O'Brien";
$str2 = "546635980E5898057";
$str3 = 42;

echo mysql_real_escape_string($str1);   // output: Miles O\'Brien
echo mysql_real_escape_string($str2);   // output: 546635980E5898057
echo mysql_real_escape_string($str3);   // output: 42
```

in no case would ANY escaped string suddenly come out like `'Miles O\'Brien'` unless you added those quotes yourself. e.g.

```
echo "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($str1) . "'";
```

Comment: Whoops, yeah it seems like I had single quotes in my query (`"INSERT INTO orders VALUES (0, {$fname}, {$lname}, {$address1}, {$address2}, {$town}, {$county}, {$postcode}, {$country}, {$tel}, {$email}, '', {$postage}, {$subtotal}, {$total}, {$basket},'', 'eBay', now(), 'GBP', 'paypal', 1, '', 1, '{$txnId}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE txnid=txnid, complete=complete, new=new, time=time;"`) - the problem is that if I remove them I get invalid syntax near `'\"6Y8143371T918184S\"`, which is a txnid value.